# python raw string notation with a variable. Lib.re / pypi.regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm familiar with how to use something like `pattern = re.compile(r"stuff")`  where `stuff` is whatever regex pattern I want to use.

What I am trying to figure out is there a way to use the `r` flag with a variable?  Like below

```
def getFileLike(foo):
   pattern = re.compile(r foo)
   result = re.search(pattern,"some string")
```

i've tried
`pattern = re.compile(usr_pattern, -r)`
and
`pattern = re.compile(r usr_pattern)`
but none of it compiles and they throw various errors.  So I'm sticking with something like

```
def getFilesLike(flag):
    if flag:
       pat = re.compile(r".txt")
    else:
       pat = re.compile(r".png")
```

I've also tried reading the documentation below and also searching for "raw string". I'm not finding anything.  I would love it if someone could confirm if this is possible or point me in the right direction.

[Lib.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)

[PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "raw string", there are only *raw string literals*. You can't use `r` with a variable because a variable isn't a literal.